# Using auxiliary clipboard for Windows

Tags: windows-7, clipboard

Is it possible to use an alternative clipboard in Windows 7 instead of the default one. I have researched quite a bit online but I was only able to find clipboard managers which was not what I was looking for.

Comment: What features are you looking for that a clipboard manager cannot accomplish? How's this? http://sourceforge.net/projects/ditto-cp/

Comment: @MC10 I am looking to copy contents of a file from a software which is limiting me by the number of lines. So I was wondering if there was an another clipboard that wouldn't limit me on the number of lines I can copy.

Comment: Is the software limiting you or the clipboard?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a clipboard manager?  I LOVE my clipboard manager.  You could just use it as an alternative clipboard, without taking advantage of the other features.

Comment: @mc10 the software is limiting anything that is copied to 10 lines as it uses the underlying windows copy thereby limiting the clipboard manager.

Comment: @aparente001 I used kana clip but still the copy had a message from the software appended to the copied text so that was not what I was looking for.

Comment: I use Arsclip and I love it.  http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/

Comment: This sounds like an internal software limitation. The Clipboard is simply an area of shared memory. The program you are using refuses to place more than 10 lines on there.  The only way to change that is to use another program to read that file. A proper answer is impossible here, given the lack of details about the file.

Comment: @ChrisThornton I was using a program installed as an extension in visual studio to copy the files to the clipboard. I came across this [link] (https://goo.gl/GkL6nW) extension in visual studio which copies the contents to an auxiliary clipboard. So I was wondering whether there are any stand alone programs available to do the same thing.